# What's the best way to access a website from a Windows Service?

Tags: .net, html, windows-services, screen-scraping

I'm struggling to write a Windows Service that accesses a website, logs in using stored credentials, and downloads the HTML to parse it. What do you think is the best way to go about this?

Comment: What you're doing is called screen-scraping. You'll find many references to it in Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have to do that (The webserver doesn't provide a webservice), use the HttpWebRequest (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and parse the HTML either with Regex or some html parsing lib.

Or WebClient, of course.

Comment: -1: HTML is not a regular language and cannot, in general, be parsed using regular expressions.

Comment: I think you mean *should* not. Really I believe it depends on what he wants to scrape from the page, and how much--if the data's simple a regex will suffice and is heaps faster than parsing the HTML and making a tree out of it.

Comment: +1: Hah, strange, isn't it? I've had success using regex detecting/extracting/replacing text in HTML streams.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.

Here are some examples (it's ASP.NET but the code applies equally to using in a service): [Screen Scraping, ViewState, and Authentication using ASP.Net](http://odetocode.com/articles/162.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

if it's a specific website, it's possible that you can send the required POST data immediately and bypass parsing the login page. `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` are what you need. you need to open a connection, send the post data, and then retrieve your response. a bit more complicated than I feel like going into here :)

for parsing HTML pages, I've had success with HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0):

You can host an IRobotX activex control, and run a web robot to retrieve the page.